# Does Play Store allow apps that have a webview only to my site?

Tags: android, webview

I want to publish an app witch contains a External Browser to my site only and whole app. Does Play Store allow apps that have a Webview only to my site?

I want open the website in my app using Webview. App has one button and open the Webview for viewing the website after the click of button

Comment: This is not a programming problem, this is a legal issue. We are not positioned to interpret legal agreements (what you can and can't publish to the Google Play Store is a legal agreement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Google play console team:
We don't allow apps whose primary purpose is to drive affiliate traffic to the website or provide web views of the website without the permission of the website owner or administrator.